# Passing context variable from unix shell to Parent Job and then passing it between job

Tags: shell, unix, etl, talend

I have a requirement. I am trying to pass a context variable defined in Talend(name=nomeFile, value=context.nome_file) from unix to myParent Job and then I want to pass it between my jobs. In this case the variable must be read from mainALF and passed to subLoad_Alf. I developed both ParentJob and ChildJob and after that I build myParentJob. At this point from unix terminal I wrote the following command:

./myParentJob.sh --context_param nomeFile="myDirectory/FileName.txt" and I does not work. I got "No such file or directory".

This is my main Job (myParentJob):

[image]

On the contrary, If I build myChildJob(subLoad_Alf) and I run the same command: ./myChildJob.sh --context_param nomeFile="myDirectory/FileName.txt" it works.

I think I am not able to read the context variable (nomeFile) in the ParentJob and send its value ("myDirectory/FileName.txt") to myChildJob.
This is my childJob config:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone can help me to figure out how to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Have you created the context variable nomeFile in your parent job ? Could you please show the parent job ?

Comment: Yes, I created the context variable in myParentJob which is the 1st attached pictures. The variable must be read and passed to subLoad_Alf

Comment: Ok, but unless I'm mistaken, both your screenshots show the child job subLoad_Alf. Have you checked "Transmit whole context" on the tRunJob of your child job, in the parent job ?

Comment: I put 3 screenshot...do you see the mainJob? "Transmit whole context" is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding your nomeFile context variable when you pass it to the child job.
The global variable (`globalMap.get("context.nomeFile")`) that you are using to override the context variable does not exist, hence the empty `context.nomeFile` that is passed to your child job.
Checking "Transmit whole context" on the child job's `tRunJob` will take care of passing the nomeFile that was passed to your parent job. You don't need to explicitly specify a value for that context variable so you need to remove it from context params table.

Comment: I deleted (globalMap.get("context.nomeFile"))  and as values I put context.nomeFile, but I does not working. As Parameters I have nomeFile and values context.nomeFile. What I sholud put in this field

Comment: I've updated my answer. You don't need to put anything so you could just remove it. Please try and keep me posted.